# Selenium Python, Web driver wait locates an element, find element does not

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

Below code works fine in firefox without the `sleep(1)`. 
But in chrome, `driver.find_element_by_xpath` fails.
If there is `sleep(1)` in between, then it works.

```
//the wait below passes fine for both Chrome and Firefox.

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span')))

//In chrome this does not find the element.Works in firefox.

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span').click()
```

In chrome shows a

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Message: element not visible
```

Below code works in both Chrome and Firefox

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span')))

sleep (1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span').click()
```

Comment: seems that chrome takes up time to show up the element as compared to firefox.

Comment: Chrome actually does find the element, it's just not **visible** yet. Instead of wait until presence of element located, try using wait until visibility of element located. See [Expected Conditions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/051c8b110a1aec35247cd45fa4db85c6e522cdcb/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L61)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot click on an element that is not yet visible, use expected condition visibility_of_element_located instead:

```
// Wait until element is visible    
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span').click()
```

Or better yet, since you're trying to click on it, you can also wait until element is clickable:

```
// Wait until element is clickable
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="taketour"]/div/div[1]/a/span').click()
```

See [Expected Conditions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/051c8b110a1aec35247cd45fa4db85c6e522cdcb/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py) for more built convenience methods you can use to check for element states.